# Filter rows by checking all columns for a partial text

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I'm new to R and I cant find a way to check all columns of a row if they contain a word and then just take rows which have this word at least 1 time in any column. I've made an example Dataframe to show you how my Data looks like.

```
> df
   Name currrent.Category Category.Month.1 Category.Month.2 Category.Month.3
1 Fund1      Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious
2 Fund2      Abc Cautious       Abc Global     Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious
3 Fund3        Abc Global       Abc Global       Abc Global       Abc Global
4 Fund4        Abc Global     Abc Cautious       Abc Global       Abc Global
```

And now I would like to extract all rows which have ever been in a category that contains the word "Cautious". So the returning dataframe should contain rows 1, 2 and 4. I've added Abc to every category because the category names in my data are longer and differ in some ways but the important thing is if they contain the word "Cautious" or not.

Is an operation like this possible in R?

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Fund1", "Fund2", 
"Fund3", "Fund4"), class = "factor"), currrent.Category = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Abc Cautious", "Abc Global"), class = "factor"), 
Category.Month.1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Abc Cautious", 
"Abc Global"), class = "factor"), Category.Month.2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Abc Cautious", "Abc Global"), class = "factor"), 
Category.Month.3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Abc Cautious", 
"Abc Global"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "currrent.Category", 
"Category.Month.1", "Category.Month.2", "Category.Month.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I hope this is the right way to post dput().

Comment: is it right like this?

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: Or just `df[rowSums(sapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = "Cautious", fixed = TRUE)) > 0,]` Or ```df[Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = "Cautious", fixed = TRUE)) > 0,]```  with base R

Comment: Also ```df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = "Cautious", fixed = TRUE)),]```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is not [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), that's why you're having problems dealing with it. I can see a `season` and a `status` for that season in your data.

`gather` comes from the `tidyr` package, `filter` and the *magrittr* operator (`%>%`) come from `dplyr` package. I use the right assignment `->` to keep the flow of the data from left to right.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(season, status, -Name) %>% 
  filter(grepl("Cautious", status)) ->
  dcautious
```

You can add eg `group_by(Name) %>% summarise(ncautious=n())` to get a list of funds with the number of cautions in the data set.

Comment: Thank you again. It worked. Now I just get the Funds that contain "Cautious" in any Category.

Comment: This seems like a somewhat cumbersome approach to a fundamentally simple problem.

Comment: @mtoto Always depends on your point of view. Keeping the data in the original 'cumbersome' representation brings you problems with plotting and other downstream analyses. Your solution does the job, but with the lambda function and length I'd argue it's less legible.. I prefer verbs that align with my mental model of what I'm actually doing with the data. Here I `filter` the data on match in `status`.

Answer (score 3):

In `base` R

```
# Extract rows that contain "Cautious" more than once
sub <- apply(df, 1, function(row) length(grep("Cautious", row)) > 0) 

# Subset df
df[sub,]
#   Name currrent.Category Category.Month.1 Category.Month.2 Category.Month.3
#1 Fund1      Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious
#2 Fund2      Abc Cautious       Abc Global     Abc Cautious     Abc Cautious
#4 Fund4        Abc Global     Abc Cautious       Abc Global       Abc Global
```

Comment: Or perhaps this variation using the `grepl` function: `df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(grepl("Cautious", x))), ]` .  The apply gives a logical vector which is then used to subscript `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sqldf` package :

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where 
[Name] like '%Cautious%' or 
[currrent.Category] like '%Cautious%' 
or [Category.Month.1] like '%Cautious%' 
or [Category.Month.2] like '%Cautious%' 
or [Category.Month.3] like '%Cautious%'")
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much! But in my original Data Frame I have over 300 columns. Is there a way to include all columns without mentioning them explicitly, like a sequence? I've just tried this and it did not work. sqldf("select * from df where [Name]:[Category.Month.3] like '%Cautious%'")

Comment: Well you didnt mention that. The below answer should help.

Comment: I just tired Name:Category in hope it would check all columns from Name to Category.Month.3 :)

Comment: Suggest generalizing the answer like this: `library(sqldf); where <- paste(paste0("[", names(df)[-1], "] like '%Cautious'"), collapse = " or "); fn$sqldf("select * from df where $where")`

Comment: You are a genius @G.Grothendieck