# R - Filter any rows and show all columns

Tags: r

I would like to an output that shows the column names that has rows containing a string value. Assume the following...

```
       Animals        Sex
       I like Dogs    Male
       I like Cats    Male
       I like Dogs    Female
       I like Dogs    Female
       Data Missing   Male
       Data Missing   Male
```

I found an SO tread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534461/r-filter-rows-by-checking-all-columns-for-a-partial-text), David Arenburg provided answer which works very well but I was wondering if it is possible to get an output that doesn't show all the rows. So If I want to find a string "Data Missing" the output I would like to see is...

```
       Animals        
       Data Missing
```

or

```
       Animal 
       TRUE
```

instead of

```
       Anmials        Sex
       Data Missing   Male
       Data Missing   Male
```

I have also found using filters such as df$columnName works but I have big file and a number of large quantity of column names, typing column names would be tedious. Assume string "Data Missing" is also in other columns and there could be different type of strings. So that is why I like David Arenburg's answer, so bear in mind I don't have two columns, as sample given above.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is grep for "Data Missing" like this:

```
x <- apply(data, 2, grep, pattern = "Data Missing")
lapply(x, length) > 1
```

This will give you the:

```
Animal 
TRUE
```

result you're after. It's also good because it checks all columns, which you mentioned was something you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If we want only the first row where it matches, use `match`

```
data[match("Data Missing", data$Animals), "Animals", drop = FALSE]
#     Animals  
#5 Data Missing
```